# Convergent series consisting of element-wise product of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If we have two non-negative sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that:

- $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n<\infty$ converges;
- $b_n$ is bounded for any $n$;
- $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n<\infty$ converges;

What can we say about the sequence $b_n$ (can we say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b_n=0$)?

Comment: What do you mean by bounded for any $n$? That the sequence $b_n$ is bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take $b_n = 1$ for all n, then $\sum a_n*b_n = \sum a_n < \infty$

This is actually true for any bounded sequence $b_n$, s.t. $|b_n|< C$, because $a_n$ being non-negative and $\sum a_n$ converging, implies $\sum a_n$ is absolutely-convergent and therefor:

$\sum|a_n*b_n| \leq \sum|a_n|*C=C*\sum a_n<\infty $

So $\sum a_n*b_n$ converges absolutely and thereby also converges.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!